# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Кто-нибудь может помочь? Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?

Выполняющий стратегическую или тактическую задачи и находящийся в длительном автономном плавании подводный флот, — дизельные или атомные подводные лодки, — относится к энергетическим установкам (ЭУ) с непрерывным производственным циклом (время или длительность автономного плавания), до завершения которого остановка объекта для проведения планово­-предупредительных и ремонтных работ по восстановлению работоспособности или замене отказавшего агрегата или его уплотнительного узла путем отсоединения от пневмогидросистемы объекта для последующей разборки корпусной арматуры недопустима условиями эксплуатации и небезопасна для обслуживающего корабль экипажа.

Answer (score 1):

Флот относится к ЭУ? Флот может находиться в длительном автономном плавании?!

Флот надо вообще убрать. Это всё лодки.

"Недопустима" заменить на "не допускается"

И вообще – такие длинные предложения недопустимы. Не допускаются! ))

Comment: Действительно, предложение чересчур громоздкое.

Answer (score 1):

Выполняющий стратегическую или тактическую задачу и находящийся в длительном автономном плавании подводный флот — дизельные или атомные подводные лодки — относится к энергетическим установкам (ЭУ) с непрерывным производственным циклом (время или длительность автономного плавания), до завершения которого остановка объекта для проведения планово­-предупредительных и ремонтных работ по восстановлению работоспособности или замене отказавшего агрегата или его уплотнительного узла путем отсоединения от пневмогидросистемы объекта для последующей разборки корпусной арматуры недопустима согласно условиям эксплуатации и небезопасна для обслуживающего корабль экипажа.

Первые две запятые  убрать, иначе запятая стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые расставлены верно. Вот только тире не к месту. Тире здесь допустимо, если предложение "дизельные или атомные подводные лодки" является вставной конструкцией.  На мой взгляд, здесь нет никакой вставной конструкции. Посмотрим, что скажут другие.

Comment: А мне кажется, что тире нужно, т.к. здесь поясняется, что флот - это дизельные или атомные подводные лодки, а вот запятые у тире - лишние.
____
Т.е. либо запятые, либо тире.

Comment: Да, если поясняется, что флот - это дизельные или атомные подводные лодки,то тире необходимо. Запятые же отделяют два причастных оборота , соединенных союзом "и".

Comment: А зачем их выделять? Эти обороты стоят перед определяемым словом. В этой позиции не надо выделять.